# What is the order of tasks when refitting a bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

I need to completely refit my bathroom, including the following tasks:

- Replace an old boiler (involves removing an immersion heater from the first floor, adjusting gas supply and changing pipe work)
- Strip out and fit new units
- Fit a shower (there is currently no shower piping - just a tap attachment in the bath)
- Move a radiator
- Plaster a damp/rotting wall
- Tile the floor and walls
- Install new extractor fan
- Hang a shower curtain

I have no idea which order to tackle the tasks. Should I tile the floor and walls before fitting units? or do you tile around fitted units?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4):

The advantage of tiling first are that you don't have to cut as many tiles - just those at the room corners and around pipes. Certain areas will be easier to tile too.

The disadvantage is that you need more tiles. You will also need to make sure that all pipes are in the correct location but not connected. This will mean either having the water turned off or fitting isolation valves (of itself not a bad idea).

Comment: It also means that should you decide to change out the cabinets, or switch to a pedestal, you might be able to do it without redoing the tile, too.  ... and the tile laying might be easier, as you're not working in as cramped space.